# Create New Category FakeStoreApi Vuejs Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch-api, nuxt3

I would like to know how to change the category with FakeStore API.
I have made some test and I don't understand how to use the API. Is it possible to change a category or not?

Here is what the docs say:

```
fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products',{
            method:"POST",
            body:JSON.stringify(
                {
                    title: 'test product',
                    price: 13.5,
                    description: 'lorem ipsum set',
                    image: 'https://i.pravatar.cc',
                    category: 'electronic'
                }
            )
        })
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(json=>console.log(json))
```

And Here what i've done

```
const fakeStoreURL = "https://fakestoreapi.com";

export default function () {
  const getProducts = async (): Promise<Product[]> => {
    const respone = await $fetch<Product[]>(`${fakeStoreURL}/products`);
    return respone;
  };

  const getProductById = async (id: number): Promise<Product> => {
    const respone = await $fetch<Product>(`${fakeStoreURL}/products/${id}`);
    return respone;
  };

  const getProductsByCategory = async (category: string): Promise<Product> => {
    const respone = await $fetch<Product>(
      `${fakeStoreURL}/products/category/${category}`
    );
    return respone;
  };

  return {
    getProducts,
    getProductById,
    getProductsByCategory,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[As from the docs](https://fakestoreapi.com/docs) You need to use `PUT` with that *ID*:

```
Update a product

fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/7',{ // Notice the 7 which is the wanted product
            method:"PUT", // PUT instead of POST
            body:JSON.stringify(
                {
                    title: 'test product',
                    price: 13.5,
                    description: 'lorem ipsum set',
                    image: 'https://i.pravatar.cc',
                    category: 'electronic' // Your category update
                }
            )
        })
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(json=>console.log(json))
```

Comment: In which file do i have to put this ? Look my code Thanks

Comment: it's a fetch request, it can go practically anywhere.  in general, code goes where you need it... it's your decision as the developer where that is.  we know nothing about your app's architecture or why you're doing this in the first place or what you plan to do with the result, so it's not realistic to ask someone else where it should go.